# Difference between crash point & degradation in Load testing

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I want to know, what do you mean by crash point & degradation in Load testing?

What are the differences between crash point & degradation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find degradation when doing [load testing](https://support.smartbear.com/loadcomplete/docs/use-cases/checking-whether-server-supports-n-users.html) while you tuning the number of maximum concurrent users

> One of the main load testing goals is to verify that your web server can work correctly with certain number of concurrent users.

You will find crash point when doing [stress testing](https://support.smartbear.com/loadcomplete/docs/use-cases/stress-testing.html) and trying to find a way to crash your application

> The purpose of web server stress testing is to find the target application’s crash point.
>
> The crash point is not always an error message or access violation. It can be a perceptible slowdown in the request processing.

Answer (score 0):

Crash Point is a point where the sever or AUT stops responding or crashes.

Degradation point is a point from where the performance of the server/AUT starts degrading but still in working condition with slower response.